# How can I fix a broken dark theme and menus in the Libreoffice 6.2 snap?

Tags: 18.04, themes, libreoffice, snap

Overnight my snap must have updated to 6.2. Now there is a dark theme and the top bar menus are completely useless.  They are transparent with white text so I can't read any of the text. If I get to the options dialogs, they write over each other and don't refresh so eventually just become a jumbled mess with no way to change anything.  I did a snap revert and now it says it is running 6.1.4 but the menus are still corrupt.  Is there something else I need to revert.  I have 10 non tech uses that I switched to snaps so they would stay up to date and I'm sure the phone calls will start soon because all 3 of my main computers all look the same.[image]

```
Name                  Version         Rev   Tracking  Publisher   Notes    
chromium              72.0.3626.96    595   stable    canonical✓  -    
communitheme          0.1             1593  stable    didrocks    -    
core                  16-2.37.2       6405  stable    canonical✓  core    
core18                18              719   stable    canonical✓  base    
gnome-3-26-1604       3.26.0          78    stable/…  canonical✓  -    
gnome-calculator      3.30.1          260   stable/…  canonical✓  -    
gnome-calendar        3.30.0          52    stable    canonical✓  -    
gnome-characters      3.30.0          139   stable/…  canonical✓  -    
gnome-logs            3.30.0          45    stable/…  canonical✓  -    
gnome-system-monitor  3.30.0          57    stable/…  canonical✓  -    
gnucash-jz            2.6.21a         43    stable    jz          -    
gtk-common-themes     0.1-7-g1feddba  1122  stable/…  canonical✓  -    
libreoffice           6.2.0.3         104   stable    canonical✓  -    
syncthing             1.0.1           334   stable    syncthing✓  -
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be an issue with the communitheme snap.  On 3 different computers I can toggle the problem on and off by either logging in using the "Ubuntu" theme or by using Gnome Tweaks to switch the theme elements to default. I haven't received any kind of confirmation as of this post but I filed an issue at https://github.com/ubuntu/yaru/issues/1194